# "Buveuse taraudeuse ornée de bernés..." What's the right explanation?

Tags: vocabulaire, lexique, poésie

En lisant un poème d'Henri Michaud ([*Année maudite*](http://www.artpoetique.fr/poemes/annee_maudite.php)), je suis tombé sur les lignes suivantes :

> Buveuse
> taraudeuse
> ornée de bernés
> Année, la narine au vent
> mais rien ne vient
> Souffrance
> sur ta coque vide !

Pour autant que je sache, "Buveuse" n'est pas seulement une femme qui boit, mais aussi le nom d'une espèce de papillon de nuit. Alors que signifie l'expression "Buveuse taraudeuse ornée de bernés" ? Après tout, "berné" signifie tout autre chose. De quoi le papillon est-il orné ?

Peut-être, je ne comprends pas vraiment le sens de ce qui est écrit et donc je vous demande de m'aider et de déchiffrer ce rébus.

P.S. Je suis désolé pour les erreurs éventuelles - ma deuxième langue est l'anglais :)

Comment: Ceci n'est que mon avis personnel, je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit le sens à donner à la phrase, tout juste une piste en me plaçant dans le contexte du poème entier. La référence au vin plus loin me dit que la buveuse est une personne au féminin. Ici c'est l'Année qui est personnifiée. « Année maudite, année nausée », année qui taraude (c'est à dire tourmente), elle tourmente ceux qui l'ornent (→la remplissent) et qui sont bernés (→trompés), ils attendent qu'elle donne un peu de son vin mais n'ont que souffrance, anxiété, famine...

Answer (score 1):

Comme None l'a écrit en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/buveuse-taraudeuse-orn%C3%A9e-de-bern%C3%A9s-whats-the-right-explanation/50545#comment104932_50538), *Buveuse, taraudeuse, ornée de bernés* qualifient l'année qui est le sujet de ce poème.

Il a été écrit durant la deuxième guerre mondiale. Les années de guerre qui s'égrenaient ont certainement motivé la noirceur du texte.

*Buveuse* peut être mis en parallèle avec *Qu'un sang impur abreuve nos sillons*.

Comment: Thank you so much! Surrealist poetry got a little closer to me :)